# Android: How to scroll ScrollView in top

Tags: android

I have two buttons that switching to the next list of events and the previous one.

When I go to next\previous event, scrolls remains somewhere below. But I need to "rewind" it up.

I'm trying:

```
scrollViewEventDetails.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

and:

```
scrollViewEventDetails.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

but it doesn't work. Please, help!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You shoud write next:

```
scrollViewEventDetails.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);//if you move at the end of the scroll

scrollViewEventDetails.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);//if you move at the middle of the scroll
```

Answer (score 23):

This did not work for me:

```
scrollViewEventDetails.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP); //if you move at the end of the scroll
```

This worked for me:

```
scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 14):

`scrollview.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);` is more consistent and worked for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

The timing of these calls is crucial. getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener didn't work for me but using the onWindowFocusChanged callback in my activity did:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (hasFocus) {
            mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but there is a reason the code will work some places and not others. It will get interrupted by the main thread if called in the wrong place, especially if the ScrollView must scroll a large distance. Therefore put your call in its own thread. Fixed.

```
(new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
   }
})).start();
```